# json parse error for html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

My problem is html content not being parsed with `JSON.parse` .

1. I am getting input from a content editable div.

   `var content = $("#contentInput").html();`
2. I am sending it to server after `JSON.stringify`

   `var dataToServer= JSON.stringify(content); //sending an object`
3. The same content I am getting from server, and I attempting to parse it.;

   `var dataFromServer = JSON.parse(content);`

Here my problem raises parser throwing error. content of html data receiving as it is.

I was tried `eval` but after reading the [some articles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx) I was withdrawn my decision.

How to resolve the problem.

Comment: Why are you `JSON.stringify`ing a string?

Comment: @Musa: That's what suprised me too :)

Comment: i was sending an object with content  to server that's way JSON.stringify

Comment: How are you sending the data to the server? I'm pretty sure you don't need `JSON` at all!

Comment: i have some other fields to send with content i must need json

Comment: How are you getting `dataFromServer`? Your tags mention jQuery: if you tell its AJAX functions you're getting JSON, or it detects that the response is JSON, it will automatically parse it for you, and you may just be trying to re-parsing some JSON that was already parsed for you.

Comment: @JohnFlatness no I am not getting JSON from AJAX its a JSON object coming from server as a string so I need to parse it.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to post something more: the code you're using to send/receive from the server, or at least what `dataFromServer` looks like before you try to parse it.

Comment: @John I was printed the sending and receiving contents, they are same but JSON.parse not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is [fiidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mytME/4/) of working code.

The problem is your server corrupting the content. Please check out your server code, it may add some non printable charaecters.

JSON.parse fails if the content not in JSON format. It strictly follow the rules of jsonstring to parse it( I mean double quotations and other /).

Your server may be adding some other unuseful characters to content or jsonstring.

Comment: How do you check for / remove these non printable characters?

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify expects a javascript object. Try like this:

```
var content = $("#contentInput").html();
var dataToServer = JSON.stringify({ html: content });
...
var dataFromServer = JSON.parse(dataToServer);
var content = dataFromServer.html;
```

Comment: its not working yar! thats way i was posted the question. Please the question properly.

Comment: `stringify` on a string is perfectly legal. There may not be much of a point in doing it if you know you're always dealing with just strings, but there's nothing *wrong* with it: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify('foo')) === 'foo'`.

Comment: @rameshbabu, what error do you get? Does the browser that you are using support the `JSON.stringify` method?